# MS Access stopping Insert command on form close

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I've been working in Access on a project and the longer I work on it the more disdain I have for it. I've been googling and attempting workarounds all day but I can't quite find what I am trying to do.

I have a form that is linked to a table. I have one button that will set the record of the form to a new record. If you start typing into any one of the text boxes the record starts updating, it's not really doing an insert at this point. However if I navigate off the record the update is called. there isn't anything I can do to stop the update from happening if the user does not want to add a new record that I can find. I'm using

```
 DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

To get the form to have all the text boxes go to a new record. At this point as soon as you start typing into any of the text boxes you can't go back. The autonumber will incriment and I have sku builder that concatenates the autoNumber to a prefix to act as a serial number.

What I need to do, is figure out a way to get the update to cancel if the user clicks close. I've tried to disable close, but you can always right click the bar and select close from there. This, along with anything that prompts the form to close commits that in process record and subsequently fires the "afterUpdate" event. I read some Microsoft documentation and "form_unload" is called first in the workflow but insert always goes before that. I've also tried to use the "beforeUpdate" but that fires as soon as you attempt to write into one of the boxes and not right before "afterUpdate"

It seems there is a pretty huge hole in the space between beforeUpdate and afterUpdate. I don't think this is a terribly complicated operation I'm trying to attempt here but perhaps I've been working on it for so long I have missed a simpler solution. I just need to cancel the insert operation or prompt the user that they are closing the form with an open record. If they hit no insert will fire, and yes it will.

Also, I have no appetite to rewrite for ADO because of my timeline. I just need to quickly throw some forms together and get it done. There are also a ton of fields that I don't want to setup for an ADO insert. They are all built but I have this one issue that is giving me grief and I need to apply this solution to all the forms.

TLDR - Stopping a databound form from inserting if the user has entered text and tries to exit the form.

Solution Edit:
Change the form to modal/popup and disable close.
Add a button to handle close.
Add boolean flag

```
 Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
 NR = True
 End Sub
```

Then add the code for the close button.

```
 Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
 Dim msgRes As VbMsgBoxResult

If NR Then
     msgRes = MsgBox("Do you want to save the current new record?", vbYesNoCancel, "Closing form...")
     If msgRes = vbYes Then
         DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
         DoCmd.Close
     ElseIf msgRes = vbNo Then
         Me.Undo
         DoCmd.Close
     End If
 End If
 DoCmd.Close



 End Sub
```

Comment: This is your main problem : "The autonumber will incriment and I have sku builder that concatenates the autoNumber to a prefix to act as a serial number." You have an autonumber that means something. This is never recommended. An autonumber is just there to be unique and nothing else. An autonumber can jump, go backwards or even go negative, so it is never suitable as a meaningful number and should never even be shown to a user.

Comment: I wasn't aware that an auto number set to increment could go negative, or backwards. Maybe serial number was a bad choice of words. It's not terribly meaningful but I just needed a way of building a sku with unique numbers. It's to be used as a foreign key to other tables. The attachment of the prefix only serves to identify it really.

Comment: For the most part it will increment, but you cannot rely on an autonumber to be anything except unique. It is not difficult to run code that changes how it works. ( http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html )

Comment: Holy cow. I had a built in indexer that I wrote that would retrieve the index and +1 it on insert but I went this approach because it seemed more solid. In the grand scheme, I don't think it matters for this project but I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do either a `Me.Undo` or `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo` on FormClose
OR if you still can't get it to work (I've spent a lot of time in Access and I know it can be finicky) you can do a `DoCmd.RunSql ("Delete * from TableName where Id=NewID")`

You can also try this:

```
DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 8, , acMenuVer70
DoCmd.Close , , acSaveNo
```

You may also want to disable the close button and create a button to cancel the record so you can put all the code in there. If you set the form mode to a dialog you shouldn't be able to right click close it.

Comment: And now I want the past few hours back. Thanks sir.

Comment: DoMenuItem went out of use back in the 2000 version (or maybe even '97?).